# How to use Butterknife with onClickListener in Activity?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, butterknife

I'm looking the answer how to make onClickListener button located in Recycleview Item using Butterknife. I know how to do it without Butterknife, but I can't find anything with Bt.
Does Bt supports this?

Comment: Please provide some code so that we can understand exactly what you doing and help you with this.

Comment: use BK to bind the listener in the RV viewholder, then propagate the event to the activity. Do not try to bind it directly in the activity

Comment: Do you know any example?

Answer (score 0):

Try to learn from the sample code at [official site](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)
If you want to implement the click logic in the activity then here are the steps.

1 Create an interface

```
    public interface ClickHandler{
             void onClick(int position);
         }
```

2 Implement CLickHandler in activity

```
    MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ClickHandler{
    ...
    public void onclick(int position){
        Log.d("Check","Clicked at" + position);
    }
    ...
    adapter = new MyAdapter(this);//Pass the reference to activity as it implements the clickhandler.
    ...
```

}

3 Now your adapter has the reference for clickhandler. Similarly pass it to the viewholder and call the onCLick method from there.

```
    class ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.title) TextView name;
        @BindView(R.id.job_title) TextView jobTitle;
        ClickHandler clickHandler;

        public ViewHolder(View view, ClickHandler) {
          ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
          this.clickHandler = clickHandler;
        }

        @OnClick(R.id.submit)
         public void submit(View view) {
           if(clickHandler(!=null){
              clickHandler.onClick(getAdapterPosition());
           }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I know that. I need to create listener in Activity.

Comment: I used different solution and it works. But thank you after all.

Answer (score 0):

```
' class ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.title) TextView name;
    @BindView(R.id.job_title) TextView jobTitle;

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
      ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.submit)
     public void submit(View view) {
       // TODO submit data to server...
    }
  }'
```